# What's a good tool to screen-scrape with Javascript support?

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

Is there a good test suite or tool set that can automate website navigation -- with Javascript support -- and collect the HTML from the pages?

Of course I can scrape straight HTML with BeautifulSoup.  But this does me no good for sites that require Javascript. :)

Comment: Selenium ended up being exactly what I needed.

It is very versatile, interfaces with a number of languages, including Python, which allows me to store content and parse it, and then direct Selenium's actions based on the content returned.

Thank you all for the responses!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use [Selenium](http://selenium.dev/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/) to drive a real browser.

Ther are also some JavaScript-based headless browsers:

- [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) is a headless Webkit browser.

  - [pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) is a scraping framework based on PhantomJS and jQuery.
  - [CasperJS](http://n1k0.github.com/casperjs/) is a navigation scripting & testing utility bsaed on PhantomJS, if you need to do a little more than point at URLs to be scraped.
- [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org)

Personally, I'm most familiar with Selenium, which has support for writing automation scripts in a good number of languagues and has more mature tooling, such as the excellent [Selenium IDE](http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/) extension for Firefox, which can be used to write and run testcases, and can export test scripts to many languages.

Answer (score 6):

Using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is also a possibility.

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for
>   Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that
>   allows you to invoke pages, fill out
>   forms, click links, etc... just like
>   you do in your "normal" browser.
>
> It has fairly good JavaScript support
>   (which is constantly improving) and is
>   able to work even with quite complex
>   AJAX libraries, simulating either
>   Firefox or Internet Explorer depending
>   on the configuration you want to use.
>
> It is typically used for testing
>   purposes or to retrieve information
>   from web sites.

Comment: I agree that HtmlUnit is good for this... and it doesn't need to have a browser to run, so you can stick it in a script and have it run automatically on a server.

Comment: It's only real javascript support is following location redirects. It isn't going to be helpful for scraping.

Answer (score 4):

Selenium now wraps htmlunit so you don´t need start a browser anymore. The new WebDriver api is very easy to use too. [The first example use htmlunit driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)

Answer (score 2):

It would be very difficult to code a solution that would work with any arbitrary site out there.  Each navigation menu implementation can be quite unique.  I've worked a great deal with scrapers, and, provided you know the site you wish to target, here is how I'd approach it.

Usually, if you analyze the particular javascript used in a nav menu, it is fairly easy to use regular expressions to pull out the entire set of variables that are used to build the navmenu.  I have never used Beautiful Soup, but from your description it sounds like it may only work on HTML elements and not be able to work inside the script tags.

If you're still having problems, or need to emulate some form POSTs or ajax, get Firefox and install the [LiveHttpHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) plugin.  This plugin will allow you to manually browse the site and capture the urls being navigated along with any cookies that are being passed during your manual browsing.  That is what you need your scraperbot to send in a request to get a valid response from the target webserver(s).   This will also capture any ajax calls being made, and in many cases the same ajax calls must be implementated in your scraper to get your desired responses.

Answer (score 2):

[Mozenda](http://www.mozenda.com/) is a great tool to use as well.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that and javascript fanciness is messing with the brower's internal DOM model of the page, and does nothing to the raw HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Selenium for this and it find that it works great.
Selenium runs in Browser and will work with Firefox, Webkit and IE.
http://selenium.openqa.org/

Answer (score 1):

@insin Watir is not IE only.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81566#83387