# Read JavaScript display value from HTML file

Tags: c#, javascript, save

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View Generated Source (After AJAX/JavaScript) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307800/view-generated-source-after-ajax-javascript-in-c-sharp)

Note : I m' not using ASP.NET and i use a c# Console project.

With a simple html document :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
eval(function(p,r,o,x,y,s){y=function(c){return(c<r?'':y(parseInt(c/r)))+((c=c%r)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(o--){s[y(o)]=x[o]||y(o)}x=[function(y){return s[y]}];y=function(){return'\\w+'};o=1};while(o--){if(x[o]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+y(o)+'\\b','g'),x[o])}}return p}('j=D^C;b=3;h=1;r=7;t=B^E;p=9;g=F^A;f=0;l=5;a=G^I;q=y^u;o=w^z;s=6;d=4;k=2;n=8;m=x^v;i=H^L;e=W^U;c=X^V;J=f^j;S=h^i;M=k^g;T=b^a;K=d^e;N=l^m;O=s^t;R=r^q;Q=n^o;P=p^c;',60,60,'^^^^^^^^^^Three4Two^Seven^One3Nine^Nine^Four4Three^Zero^OneTwoSix^Three^FourSixFive^Five8Four^One^Two^One2Eight^Five^ZeroThreeZero^Six^Nine0Seven^Four^Eight^SevenNineOne^8080^8888^10448^7095^12181^3129^88^11687^8090^3394^1337^3885^9893^12222^9090^ZeroOneNineThree^SixOneTwoOne^8000^ThreeEightThreeTwo^OneOneSixSeven^FourThreeEightZero^Eight2FourEight^Seven0ZeroNine^OneEightFiveSix^EightTwoSevenFive^Four0OneFour^808^1080^11238^10637'.split('\u005e'),0,{}))
document.write((Seven0ZeroNine^ZeroThreeZero));
</script>
```

Which Display simply "8"

I would like to get this "display" value. I need certainly Webrowser which decodes JavaScript.

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.Navigate(@"c:\1.html");
```

Comment: Please avoid prefixing your question with _C#_ or the like. That is what the tags are for.

Comment: What is your question? What do you hope to do? What have you tried?

Comment: hi, i had my anwser on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307800/view-generated-source-after-ajax-javascript-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Open a browser console (google it) and try:

```
console.log("string goes here")
```

Comment: You missed a semicolon at the end ;)

Comment: Semicolons are almost always optional in JavaScript.