# Vertical Scroll down and scroll up in Selenium WebDriver with java

Tags: java, scroll, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can anybody please help me out to automate **scroll down functionality** with **WebDriver** using **Java**?

In my case, For yahoo mail `"Sign In"` is getting displayed (**visible**) once I scroll down the mouse vertically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can scroll down vertically by using the following code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,250);");
```

Similarly, it is also possible to scroll up by changing y coordinate as negative:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

You can also use the following code:
**For scroll down:**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

**For scroll up:**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -250)", "");
```

Comment: How to know when scrolling is completed?

Comment: To make the visibility of any element sometime scrolling is needed. For example, you are going to click an element which is located at the bottom of the page. In this case, it needs down scrolling. When click is succeeded, it means scrolling is done and link at the bottom is visible.

Answer (score 12):

**Scrolling to an Element of a page:**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();"
                                                              ,webElement);
```

Comment: Awesome, this works nicely. I've been trying this for hours and none of the other options worked

Comment: Great for focusing an element before taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Scrolling up should be as below:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,-250);");
```

Comment: Caren is right. no need to change the x coordinate. y coordinate should be negative to scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the height of the page and you are gonna scroll down to the down part of the page you can find the main frame of that page and use following code to scroll down without using scroll or scrollBy

```
scr1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", scr1)
```

This will automatically go to the far down of the page. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/tahamokfi/Insta/blob/master/My_Followers.py).