# Why does the JavaScript scroll() function behave in reverse?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

From this thread:
[Vertical Scroll down and scroll up in Selenium WebDriver with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554370/vertical-scroll-down-and-scroll-up-in-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

I understand that `scroll(xpos, ypos)` needs:

- positive value - scroll down
- negative value - scroll up

However, isn't it that in the Cartesian Plane, down is negative for y-axis?
[image]

If anyone can clarify, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The browser lives on an inverted Cartesian plane. 0,0 is the top left corner ... because we read top to bottom, not bottom to top - in fact, in computer graphics, the Cartesian plane has been inverted in almost every application ever

Comment: Hi, does that mean giving a negative value to x scrolls to the right in an inverted Cartesian plane?

Comment: no, it's inverted, not rotated :p

Comment: Ah so the x-axis remains the same. If you could post a quick answer, I'd be glad to upvote and accept. :)

Comment: my comments are opinion, I have no facts to back them up :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I have found a highly relevant reading and also proof:

[Why is the origin in computer graphics coordinates at the top left?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/why-is-the-origin-in-computer-graphics-coordinates-at-the-top-left)

And since browsers display through a monitor, the same applies.