# Page scroll up or down in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, selenium-rc

I have written the following code in Selenium 1 (a.k.a Selenium RC) for page scrolling using java:

```
selenium.getEval("scrollBy(0, 250)");
```

What is the equivalent code in Selenium 2 (WebDriver)?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

*Scenario/Test steps:*

1. Open a browser and navigate to [TestURL](https://www.linkedin.com/)
2. Scroll down some pixel and scroll up

For **Scroll down**:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
```

OR, you can do as follows:

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
```

For **Scroll up**:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)");
OR,
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

**Scroll to the bottom of the page:**

*Scenario/Test steps:*

1. Open a browser and navigate to [TestURL](https://www.linkedin.com/)
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page

***Way 1: By using JavaScriptExecutor***

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

***Way 2: By pressing ctrl+end***

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END);
```

***Way 3: By using Java Robot class***

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_END);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_END);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: The above code is for scroll down. For scroll up: jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)"); Only the value would be reverse

Comment: No - that will scroll to the right. Scroll up will be `scroll(0,-250)`

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Both scroll(250,0) and scroll(0,-250) should work for scroll up.

Comment: For scroll up (0, -250) is logical. I do agree with Stephen.

Comment: jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", ""); it works fine. I want to use variable as int y = 250; jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,y)", ""); An error shows in this case as "y is not defined". How to use variable in this case?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim Did you ever find a solution for that issue?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim you would just concatenate the variable into your string in whatever way you like, e.g. jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0," + y + ")", "")

Answer (score 44):

**Scrolling to the bottom of a page:**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Comment: just to mention, it is for scroll down

Comment: it is not working in my salesforce application, where as window.scrollBy(0,250) works. But it does not scroll to the end of the page.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan did you try window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)?

Answer (score 16):

There are many ways to scroll up and down in Selenium Webdriver I always use Java Script to do the same.

Below is the code which always works for me if I want to scroll up or down

```
 // This  will scroll page 400 pixel vertical
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");
```

You can get full code from here [Scroll Page in Selenium](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-scroll-a-page-in-selenium-webdriver/)

If you want to scroll for a element then below piece of code will work for you.

```
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```

You will get the full doc here [Scroll for specific Element](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-scroll-into-view-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: This worked if I have to scroll down. How can I scroll up the page?

Comment: The first snippet of code only scrolls the page, not the element itself, how can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

This may not be an exact answer to your question (in terms of WebDriver), but I've found that the `java.awt` library is more stable than `selenium.Keys`.
So, a page down action using the former will be:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
```

**Scroll down:**

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

**Scroll up:**

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, -document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```java
Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);
WebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='jobreslist_outercontainer']/div/div[2]/div"));

// drag downwards
int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = 50;
for (int i = 10; i < 500; i += numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown) {
    try {
        // this causes a gradual drag of the scroll bar, 10 units at a time
        dragger.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
    } catch(Exception e1) {}
}

// now drag opposite way (downwards)
numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = -50;
for (int i = 500; i > 10; i += numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown) {
    // this causes a gradual drag of the scroll bar, -10 units at a time
    dragger.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
}
```

Comment: I actually like this since it scrolls how a user would

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript

We can scroll to a specific element:

```js
const element = await driver.findElement(...)
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
await driver.sleep(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a scroll to the page to select all elements using:

```
Selenium.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
```

If you have a large list, add the scroll several times through the execution. Note the scroll only go to a certain point in the page for example `(0, 450)`.

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to use JavaScript, or any external libraries, so this was my solution (C#):

```
IWebElement body = Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));

IAction scrollDown = new Actions(Driver)
    .MoveToElement(body, body.Size.Width - 10, 15) // position mouse over scrollbar
    .ClickAndHold()
    .MoveByOffset(0, 50) // scroll down
    .Release()
    .Build();

scrollDown.Perform();
```

You can also easily make this an extension method for scrolling up or down on any element.

Comment: @raffamaiden put heads on your browser lol... I'm not sure why anyone would want to test against a browser that their users aren't actually going to use anyways

Comment: You are right. But the OP did not specify it was testing an app. You can use Selenium also for other purposes (e.g. webscraping).

Answer (score 1):

1.To scroll page to the bottom use window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight) as parameter

//Code to navigate to bottom

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jsExecuter = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecuter.executeScript(window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight));
```

2.To scroll page to the top use window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollTop) as parameter

//Code to navigate to top

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jsExecuter = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecuter.executeScript(window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollTop));
```

3.To scroll page to the Left use window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollLeft) as parameter

//Code to navigate to left

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jsExecuter = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecuter.executeScript(window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollLeft));
```

4.To scroll to certain point 
window.scrollTo(0,500) as parameter

//Code to navigate to certain point e.g. 500 is passed as value here

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jsExecuter = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecuter.executeScript(window.scrollTo(0,500));
```

To check the navigation directly in browser , open developers tool in browser and navigate to console.
Execute the command on console window.scrollTo(0,400)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

This code works for me. As the page which I'm testing, loads as we scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript executor always does the job perfectly:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,300)");
```

where `(0,300)` are the horizontal and vertical distances respectively. Put your distances as per your requirements.

If you a perfectionist and like to get the exact distance you like to scroll up to on the first attempt, use this tool, [MeasureIt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/measureit/). It's a brilliant firefox add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Ripon Al Wasim's answer. I did some improvement. because of network problems, I retry three times until break loop.

```py
driver.get(url)
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
try_times = 0
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,2000)")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(scroll_delay)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    if last_height == new_height:
        try_times += 1

    if try_times > 3:
        try_times = 0
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

JavascriptExecutor is best to scroll down a web page
`window.scrollTo` Function in JavascriptExecutor can do this

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,100");
```

Above code will scroll down by 100 y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)");
```

Answer (score -2):

1. If you want to scroll the page vertically to perform some action, you can do it using the following JavaScript.
       **((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scrollTo(0,
   document.body.scrollHeight)”);**

   ```
       Where ‘JavascriptExecutor’ is an interface, which helps executing JavaScript through Selenium WebDriver. You can use the following code to import.
   ```

**import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;**

2.If you want to scroll at a particular element, you need to use the following JavaScript.

**WebElement element =
driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//input [@id=’email’]”));((JavascriptExecutor)
driver).executeScript(“arguments[0].scrollIntoView();”, element);**

Where ‘element’ is the locator where you want to scroll.

3.If you want to scroll at a particular coordinate, use the following JavaScript.
**((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scrollBy(200,300)”);
Where ‘200,300’ are the coordinates.**

4.If you want to scroll up in a vertical direction, you can use the following JavaScript.
**((JavascriptExecutor)
driver).executeScript(“window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight,0)”);**

5. If you want to scroll horizontally in the right direction, use the following JavaScript.
   **((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scrollBy(2000,0)”);**
6. If you want to scroll horizontally in the left direction, use the following JavaScript.
   **((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scrollBy(-2000,0)”);**