# How to scroll down using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to scroll down my web page and i m using this code to scroll page but it is not working

```
public ViewBasketSentToMePageObject viewSlideShare() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread.sleep(500l);

    Actions action1 =new Actions(getDriver());
    action1.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0030')).build().perform();

    List<WebElement> function = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//a [@ng-click='onItemClick()']"));
    function.get(13).findElement(By.xpath("//img [@ng-src='resources/images/slideshare-icon-small.png']")).click();

    return getFactory().create(ViewBasketSentToMePageObject.class);
}
```

Looking for help

Comment: Your problem earlier Solved Here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using simple java script below and you can scroll the page.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
```

Comment: This still works in the latest Selenium Webdriver 4.X (which I'm shocked at).

Answer (score 6):

For scroll down:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
```

or, you can do as follows:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroll until find the `WebElement`

Try this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", your_WebElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@id='giveid']"));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Use this. This will help you to scroll down at the particular element. I had tested on my website even. It is working fine.