# Proper Java/Selenium syntax for the code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me how to get this code working?

```
String mvt = "1500";

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,mvt));
```

As you can see I want to use the number in mvt in the execution script. For now, I get the error:

```
syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

at UsingActionsClass.UsingActions.main(UsingActions.java:23)
```

So, what will be the proper syntax, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll down using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140337/how-to-scroll-down-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues. One is that you didn't close the quotes... that is what the error message is telling you. The second issue is that you aren't passing your `mvt` variable into the JS call. The corrected code is below.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0])", mvt);
```

Comment: can i use 2 or more arguments? for example:

String mvt = "1500";
  String mvt2 = "3500";
  
  //Scroll down
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0])", mvt,mvt2);

if possible what will be the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the the quotes of the JavaScript snippet, and then the parenthesis of the call:

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", mvt);
```

Comment: You fixed one problem but `mvt` is undefined the way it's written.

Comment: You are correct. The script is starting now but it is not scrolling. Can you please tell me what is the proper way to define mvt?