# selenium webdriver | unfollow all friends at social network

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

do you have any idea why it unfollow only 15 people 
instead of all?

You need an account at Instagram to run this script.

for example:
if your account is *chrome1*
than this script will be working on
https://www.instagram.com/chrome1/following/

```
for ns in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_6jvgy"):
    try:
        ns.find_element_by_class_name("_r4e4p").click() # unFollow button!!!

        # time.sleep(2) # the same as without sleep  

        unfollow_nick = ns.find_element_by_class_name("notranslate").get_attribute("title")
        print(unfollow_nick) # now: prints all, but really unfollow only 15. 

    except:
        pass
```

this question is a continuation of the previous:
[Scroll in Selenium Webdriver (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323158/scroll-in-selenium-webdriver-python)

all the code needed to run:
https://ideone.com/wYjHW4

Comment: Are you sure all the users loaded before calling this method? As I mentioned in the previous post, It is AJAX request which is loading all the users `10 at a time`, when you scroll down or entered END key.

Comment: yes, because:
1) before that loop I run  recursiveFunc(1), to scroll the list to the end.
2) prints the names of all the users from the list (~ 40).

Comment: 3) I see it, because use Chrome driver instead of PhantomJs.

Answer (score 0):

It is the speed of requests (clicking continuously on `Following` button) that causing Instagram server to reject/ignore the majority of requests.

Add some sleep time before each request.

In your code, you imported `sleep` method. so, directly use `sleep(2)` but not `time.sleep`, which throws the exception and you are capturing it & bypassed it using `pass` keyword, so you are not aware of this exception. I suggest print the exception and then use `pass` keyword.

```
for ns in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_6jvgy"):
    try:
        ns.find_element_by_class_name("_r4e4p").click() # unFollow button!!!

        sleep(2) # works now 

        unfollow_nick = ns.find_element_by_class_name("notranslate").get_attribute("title")
        print(unfollow_nick) # now: prints all, but really unfollow only 15. 

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks, I also thought this is a cause.
I agree about sleep/time.sleep. I've really imported  from time import sleep.
Yes, 'pass' is not good to the exception handling.

Comment: but it hasn't fixed the issue. When I do it manually it's as fast as without sleep and works as expected.

Comment: script: 
without sleep: 15 people; 
sleep(2) # 15; 
sleep(8) # 15.

Comment: p.s. I have a fast and stable internet (100 Mbps) and good ping.

Comment: can you see all the users following button is clicked to unfollow them? Give sleep and observe the behaviour, whether unfollow button is clicked for all following users?

Comment: yes, it have clicked unfollow button for each user.
I've increased sleep after 13rd user. I try to open Developer Tools at Chromium (f12 or Ctrl+Shift+I) but driver closes the tools instantly.

Comment: Then it might be the server. Try manually unfollowing more than 15 users in a shirt time, say 20. Check whether all users selected, are unfollowed. Otherwise, I don't see any logic here.

Comment: Yes, this is the server. After 15 requests server send a message, something like (in my profile language):
"Too many requests. Please try later.0". And the status code become 403 instead of 200.

Comment: I've checked: after 450 seconds(7.5 min) I can send another 15 requests. Sometimes need to wait even more.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        scroll_boX = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div")
        last_ht, ht = 0, 1
        #last_bt, bt = 1, 1
        while last_ht != ht:
            last_ht = ht
           # last_bt = bt
            sleep(2) 
            ht = self.driver.execute_script("""
                arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight); 
                return arguments[0].scrollHeight;
                """, scroll_box)
            sleep(2)
```