# How to scroll up using Protractor.NET?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, protractor-net

My web page is little lengthy and the **SAVE** button is at the top right-hand corner. As I input the data through Protractor.NET, the webpage scrolls down which hides the **SAVE** button, thereby throwing a **Element is not clickable at a point** error. Now inorder to save the webpage, I need to scroll up and then find the **SAVE** button and click it.

I have an example in Protractor which uses `window.scrollTo(0,0)`, but how do I implement the same in Protractor.NET

EDIT: Included code

```
public void Test()
{
     var saveBtn = NgWebDriver
                 .FindElement(By.ClassName("btnSave"))
                 .FindElement(By.ClassName("Save"));
    var btnSv = Scroller(saveBtn);
    btnSv.Click();
}


public IWebElement Scroller(IWebElement element)
{
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)NgWebDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    return element;
}
```

So the exception occurs in Scroller method while casting the `NgWebDriver` to `IJavaScriptExecutor` type

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution to scrolling up to the top in Protractor.NET

Had referred the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java) and was able to solve my problem.

The below code worked for me.

```
IWebDriver driver = MyWebDriver.WrappedDriver;
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make it complicated?

If you want to scroll to an element you can use this simple method:

```
public IWebElement ScrollToElement(IWebElement webElement)
{
      ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement);

      return webElement;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception `Unable to cast object of type 'Protractor.NgWebDriver' to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor'`

Comment: I think you get this error when you do something like this:
myProtactorElement = ScrollToElement(myProtactorElement).Click();
If so, then just change the type that function returns.

Comment: The actual problem is that the NgWebDriver does not implement the interface `OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor`. So it throws an error while casting it. Let me know if you need some code sample

Comment: Yes, please five code where you use this method. And point to line where error occurs.

Comment: Try this:
IJavaScriptExecutor js = NgWebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
And then js.ExecuteScript();

Comment: No. It does not work. Protractor.NET uses NgWebDriver which does not implement `IJavaScriptExecutor`. So, casting always returns null.

Answer (score -1):

The below code helped me to achieve the same.

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)NgDriver;
 jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", webElement);
```