# How to resolve org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, junit4

I am writing an automated test and **want to report bugs, if occur, directly in the repo at GitHub**. The step which fails in my program is the *Submit new issue* button from GitHub Issue Tracker.

Here is the code:

```
WebElement sendIssue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button"));

sendIssue.click();
```

And the exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at
> point (883, 547.7999877929688). Other element would receive the click:
> div class="modal-backdrop"></div

The following command **also does not work**:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", sendIssue);
```

How can I make it clickable? Is there any other way by which I can resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because when selenium is trying to click ,the desired element is not clickable.

You have to make sure that the Xpath provided by you is absolutely right.If you are sure about the Xpath then try the following

replace

```
WebElement sendIssue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button"));

sendIssue.click();
```

with

```
WebElement sendIssue =(WebElement)new WebDriverWait(DRIVER,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button")));
sendIssue.click();
```

If that doesn't work ,You will get an Timeout exception, In that case try incaresing the timeout amount from 10 to 20.

If it still doesn't work please post a screenshot of the HTML.

You need to write something in the issue title and description to make the issue clickable are you sure you are not making that mistake of clicking the button without writing anything in those places I am adding screenshot for your convenience.
[image: If you dont enter the valid inputs the element is not clickable]

Comment: HTML code is inserted in the problem description above.

Comment: I found out that the label-menu causes the problem. It is not clickable but once activated the drop-down menu stays open and it makes the button unreachable. If I skip the label-menu from the report and focus on the title and body alone. The program works and button clicks.

Comment: That is great as long as you found the solution. 
I asked for the HTML screenshot to make sure that the Xpath you provided was correct.If you think my answer was helpful to you a upvote will be nice

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver introduced in a previous version (v2.48) a new behavior that prevent clicks on elements that may be overlapped for something else (a fixed header or footer - for example) or may not be at your viewport (visible area of the webpage within the browser window).
You can see the debate [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1202).

To solve this you will need to scroll (up or down) to the element you're trying to click.

One approach would be something like this post:

[Page scroll up or down in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)

Another, and maybe more reasonable, way to create a issue on Github, would be using their API. Maybe it would be good to check out!

[Github API - Issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/)

Gook luck.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Instead of HTML browser this would be useful if we perform intended Web Browser

```
// Init chromedriver
String chromeDriverPath = "/Path/To/Chromedriver" ;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```