# explicit wait not working properly

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Explicit wait is not woking in the below line diver is waiting for only 70 to 100 milliseconds and error is displayed as element is not clickable :

```
WebDriverWait wait1=new WebDriverWait(driver,5000);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s']")).click();
```

Comment: could you share the error stack trace please

Comment: If you have Implicit wait in your code, you should remove that. It may cause strange bugs like this one.

Comment: n i am not using any imlicit wait

Comment: @PadmanabanGanapathy I know what's wrong here. is there any spinner on your screen ?

Comment: or any overlay screen that appear while html is loading

Comment: no there is no spinner or overlay screen inthis case onle thread.sleep is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: how to use explicit wait because some times elements is appearing quickly in that scenario if i use implicit wait or thread then driver is waiting uselessly

Comment: check this one :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858972/how-can-i-ask-the-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-few-seconds-in-java

Answer (score 1):

In that case your Element is not clickable.
Make sure the Xpath you are providing is correct.Consult the following question,make sure you are not making similar kind of mistake

[How to resolve org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205957/how-to-resolve-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception/37206713#37206713)

Comment: i am using a correct xpath because after thread.sleep the element is clicked

Comment: In that case this is just a problem of wait time.Try to debug the code , If the element is clicked when debugging ,then try 
Thread.sleep(TimeinMilSec);
In that case you will have to place an arbitrary sleep time which seems sufficient to click the element at any point.