# Java Code for page scroll down using selenium with LISA

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium with LISA. We have to scroll down to the page bottom,i tried all the selenium+java codes, but not working. I'm using chrome driver .using the below code

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;  
     je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", 
dr.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Mail")));
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java

Answer (score 1):

[`scrollIntoView(true);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method scrolls to the current element which is `arguments[0]` into the visible area of the browser window while you want to scrolling down of the page, so you should try as below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;
je.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")

dr.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Mail")));
```

Comment: My page elements are as below                                                              {<div class=col-sm-4> <input type=submit  class=btn btn-primary btn-lg value=verify> } so how to click on that button with these elements

Comment: Sorry but didn't understand what do you mean?? Do you want to click on this `<input type=submit class=btn btn-primary btn-lg value=verify>` element which is visible after scrolling down on the page??

Comment: You can click on this button as : `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary[type='submit'][value='verify']")).click();`..

Comment: Hi Saurabh Gaur thanks for the reply it is not able to click on the button

Comment: Why not able?? Is there exception or anything else??