# Unable to scrape many questions from a Quora webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning BeautifulSoup and trying to scrape links of different questions that are present on [this](https://www.quora.com/topic/Graduate-Record-Examination-GRE-1) Quora page.

As I scroll down the website, questions present in the webpage keep coming up and displayed.

When I try to scrape the links to these questions using the code below, I only get,in my case, 5 links. ie - I only get links of 5 questions even though there are lot of questions on the site.

Is there any workaround to get as many links of questions present in the webpage?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

root = 'https://www.quora.com/topic/Graduate-Record-Examination-GRE-1'
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.' }
r = requests.get(root,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

q = soup.find('div',{'class':'paged_list_wrapper'})
no=0
for i in q.find_all('div',{'class':'story_title_container'}):
    t=i.a['href']
    no=no+1
    print(root+t,'\n\n')
```

Comment: Scraping quora is against their terms of service. Read: https://www.quora.com/What-is-scraping-and-why-is-it-not-allowed-on-Quora

Comment: @coldspeed Well, I need to make a dataset from this and this is only for educational purpose. Kindly, help !!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish cannot be done with Requests and BeautifulSoup. You need to use Selenium.
Here i give the answer using selenium and chromedriver. [Download chromedriver for you chrome version](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) and install selenium `pip install -U selenium`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
browser.get("https://www.quora.com/topic/Graduate-Record-Examination-GRE-1")
time.sleep(1)
elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
no_of_pagedowns = 5
while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1
post_elems =browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='question_link']")
for post in post_elems:
    print(post.get_attribute("href"))
```

If you are using windows - `executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver.exe'`

change this variable `no_of_pagedowns = 5` to specify how many times you want to scroll down.

I got the following output

[image]

Comment: Aah !! Somebody recommended me to learn `BeautifulSoup` for web-scraping. Well, it's really annoying to be introduced to a totally new framework. I, still, hope that this can be done using `BeautifulSoup`. Can't it be?

Comment: @rahul I don't think so. You can't directly use BeautifulSoup to execute events. Also BeautifulSoup  is the first choice for web-scraping. But here you have to mimic scrolling.

Comment: You still use Beautifulsoup with selenium. Use selenium to open the browser, render the page, then the content grabbed by selenium can be passed into Beautifulsoup to parse. I’ve done it multiple times.

Comment: @chitown88 Yes. But you can't achieve the same only using Requests+bs4 combination.

Comment: @nandukk yes. You are correct. But he was wondering if he could still use Beautifulsoup. And he can, he’s just essentially switching out requests with selenium for those few lines, I do it all the time as I like working with Beautifulsoup. There’s also a package called ‘requests-html’ that allows to render dynamic pages, but you’re probably right that you’ll need selenium to scroll. I’m just not entirely familiar with ‘requests-html’

Comment: @nandukk I request you to kindly explain your piece of code briefly for the sake of good understanding. Also, I want to close the browser at the end in MacOS.

Comment: @Nandukk Is it possible for me to know how many questions have been asked related to this topic. For this, I can't scroll for `no_of_pagedowns` of times. It needs to be much larger until the page ends. How shall I achieve this?

Comment: @rahul https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982950/how-to-scroll-down-the-page-till-bottomend-page-in-the-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

The title is grabbed from the page and printed after formatting. This is one way to do it i'm sure there are many ways to do this and this only does one question.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.quora.com/Which-Deep-Learning-online-course-is-better-Coursera-specialization-VS-Udacity-Nanodegree-vs-FAST-ai"

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# grabs the text in the title
question = soup.select_one('title').text
# removes - quora at the end
x = slice(-8) 

print(question[x])
```