# How to get the image in get_attribute("style") in webdriver selenium in a page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So I'm beginner at selenium again....

I have a problem of getting the images in a web page here [ANIMEPAGE](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/)
So basically here's the console I want to `get_attribute` in this image
[image]
[image]

As you see I'm trying to get the style background image but I can't get it with these lines of code that I've search.

```
containers = driver.find_elements(by="xpath",value='//div[@class="herald box news"]')

news_link_init = []
news_intro_init = []
news_full_init = []
news_image_init = []

for container in containers:


    news_link = container.find_element(by="xpath", value="./div[@class='wrap']//h3/a").get_attribute("href")
    news_intro = container.find_element(by="xpath", value="./div[@class='wrap']//span[@class='intro']").text
    news_full = container.find_element(by="xpath", value="./div[@class='wrap']//span[@class='full']").text

// AS YOU SEE HERE I"M TRYING TO GET THE ATTRIBUTE STYLE BUT I CAN"T GET IT AND IT GIVES ME ERROR HERE
    news_image = container.find_element(by="xpath", value="./div[@class='thumbnail']").get_attribute("style")

    news_link_init.append(news_link)
    news_intro_init.append(news_intro)
    news_full_init.append(news_full)

    // Append images
    news_image_init.append(news_image)
```

As you see here in the code I'm trying to get those `background-image:url()` but I can't..can anyone help me on these ? Thanks.

**Update:** This is the always error I have receive based on two answers comment down below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `value_of_css_property` method and with a little bit of cleanup.

The code:

```py
# getting information from the image using `value_of_css_property method
news_image = container.find_element(by="xpath", value="./div[@class='thumbnail']").value_of_css_property('background-image')

## Output: 'url("https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/thumbnails/cover400x200/youtube/NKQYx6mGQPE.jpg")'

# from the get the core URL, as the value contains *url* declaration with a combination of `lstrip` and `rstrip`
news_image = news_image.lstrip('url("').rstrip('")')

## Output: https://cdn.animenewsnetwork.com/thumbnails/cover400x200/youtube/NKQYx6mGQPE.jpg
```

I haven't tested the code yet, but if it doesn't work, let me know :)

---

### Update

Images on the site loads on scroll. This is the result prior to scrolling.

[image]

This after I have manually scrolled to the end:

[image]

You need to go to the bottom of the page, then wait a bit for the images to load. Here is another post relevant to this:

[How to scroll down the page till bottom(end page) in the Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982950/how-to-scroll-down-the-page-till-bottomend-page-in-the-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: it doesn't haha

Comment: Okay. Let me open up my code editor haha

Comment: actually I think mine is wrong not yours..just check my update..

Comment: well although `./div[@class='wrap']` is working i don't understand why `./div[@class='thumbnail']` is not working...

Comment: @MythVince Solved, dude. See update. Have a great day :)

Comment: Can you give the full code sir? I don't still get it and its not still working either hahah..I'm sorry I'm just beginner at this selenium.. I don't understand the `bottom of the page` that you said in the link.

Comment: will wait for your help sir

Comment: nvm just had to pull `drive.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
`