# How to scroll to a specific element and click on it?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I scroll to a specific element and click on it?

Below is the code which I have tried:

```
Random R = new java.util.Random();
List<WebElement> Top_Stores =driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='go_body']/main/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/aside/div[1]/section[1]/a"));
WebElement randomElement = Top_Stores.get(R.nextInt(Top_Stores.size()));
String S=randomElement.getText();
System.out.println(S);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(randomElement);
actions.perform();
randomElement.click();
```

Comment: What's not working? And why do you want to scroll before you click the element?

Comment: @GalAbra While i am trying to click on element my script is not able to locate it as the element is at the bottom of the screen, So that i am trying to scroll to element location and click on it...

Comment: Below is the error i am getting:

  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (422.66668701171875, 0.399993896484375). Other element would receive the click: <nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>
      Command duration or timeout: 390 milliseconds

Comment: Your question heading `How to scroll to a specific element and click on it?` doesn't matches with the error you are seeing `WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point`which is a possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (36, 72). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-36-72-other-el)

Comment: @Debanjan if that is the case can u please help me out of this situation by clicking on the element

Comment: @NarendraChetan Edit your question heading to depict your actual problem and follow the link to solve your issue.

Comment: I simply searched on google "How to scroll in selenium" [this(click here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java) is what is got. wasn't that difficult.

Comment: Java + Selenium scrolls for you when you attempt a click. You don't need to scroll to the element yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll with javascript:

```
public void scrollToElement(WebElement element) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}
```