# Javascript scroll up and scroll down is not working in below attached page using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I have used the codes like

**For Scroll Down:**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
```

**For Scroll Up:**

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)", "");
OR,
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Its not throwing any error message. Test case is passed.

Please don't mark below link for reference because i have already verified and try to implemented that was not working so please give different solutions.

[Page scroll up or down in Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)

Comment: javascript != java

Comment: @lolynns I Agree.. ???

Comment: you tagged the post as java

Comment: Try with : js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @IPQA - Thanks Its working fine.. but one small correction in your answer that need to remove semicolon(;) from your code otherwise good.. This is correct one - js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element);

Comment: @tsivarajan - It was a typo error(semicolon)..still great to hear it worked for you.

Comment: @IPQA - Ok Np.. This helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement word1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("abc")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", word1);
```

In above code write the element which is placed at the bottom of page or at the top of page.According to which it will perform scroll up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once using actions

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
// Page Down
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
// Page Up
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.UP).perform();
```

Comment: This helps ! but not for mine scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a `handy tricky hacky stuff` over the years (I've been using Selenium for 150 years).

Whenever you're unable to scroll up a form, just ***send keys into an input*** on the top of the page. The driver will find it and will automagically scroll up the page to perform the action.

Whenever I think about this trick, I realize being an old man isn't that bad.

Good luck you fresh sailor, see you on the shores of Selenia.