# Scrolling to a paticular element in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i was trying to scrolling down to a paticular element in python , but it is not working.any Suggesstion to improve!

```
Loc_Hours =self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]")
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Loc_Hours)
Loc_Hours.text()
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -150);")
```

Comment: `Loc_Hours.text()` ??

Comment: i hope you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java

Comment: @DebanjanB The Loc_Hours is in the Middle of the page, i need to scroll down to that area and get the text.

Comment: Try `print(Loc_Hours.get_attribute('textContent'))`

Comment: @Andersson Awesome Man! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked out For Me! Just Try This if  you have Doubt.

```
print(Loc_Hours.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

Loc_Hours = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]")
ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(Loc_Hours)).perform()
```

Comment: Loc_Hours is in the Middle of the page, i need to scroll down to that area and get the text. that is my Query. @Nihal

Comment: did you try my answer? can please tell me if that is working for scrolling or not?

Comment: Am Getting ElementNotVisibleException ! @Nihal

Comment: `Loc_Hours = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]")`  are you getting error in this line? because i know that `ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(Loc_Hours)).perform()` will work

Comment: ok you got your answer from comments. good. You should post that as your answer and accept it. for the reference to other who all are having the same question

Comment: Down i have Posted his answer.@Nihal

Comment: don't use `@Andersson Answer Worked out. Thanks Man ! Am Considering`. in your answer. post that in comment of your answer. and just write this works for me. because it will be consider as thank you answer for the reviews, or may get flagged.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", Loc_Hours);
```

Comment: No, it is not Working , First i gone through this method only @Alichino after that i became stressed for finding a soultion and came here and found a Solution