# Selenium / java: how to get get total page length

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Using Selenium Java bindings.

I'm trying to write a short module that will take a full screenshot of a browser page (I know [AShot](https://github.com/pazone/ashot) exists but it is not maintained and has some issues for me).

As part of this I would like to know what the full page length is that I'm dealing with so I can calculate the number of shots I need to take, and any remainder at the bottom. There are many examples out there showing how to scroll to the bottom of a page (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)), but I am wondering if there is a way to make the `JavascriptExecutor` return the value of the page length so I can use it in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [scrollHeight](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window)

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;         
js.executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight");
```

After looking further for a more robust solution, this Javascript-code (which I took from the same [website](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window#width-height-of-the-document)) should provide a better result:

```
let scrollHeight = Math.max(
  document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
  document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
  document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);

return scrollHeight;
```

Comment: It was the `return` statement in JS that I didn't realise you could use - my JS is rudimentary to say the least. This will come in very useful in general, I think. Thanks again.

Comment: I wasn't sure what the main focus of your question was, but I am happy it helped. You should be able to cast the return of .executeScript as a String and then go from there.

Comment: I would cast it as a number (`long` I think?) and use it that way instead of a string.

Comment: @JeffC: In my personal experience Selenium behaves weird sometimes and directly casting to a numerical value could have you running into an exception. String should always work and you can double check on the Java side. That was my thinking behind it, but heck, no risk, no fun.