# Selenium cannot find elements that are not immediately in view

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

I'm having an issue with Selenium. The code below in question is working and can log everything I need, but it can only log up until 10 - coincidently 10 is the number of products I see on the page without scrolling down so my suspicion is it cannot click on these since they're technically not in view and a scrolling action would be needed or something that makes that element visible. I have tried several ways to do this but I was unable to find an elegant up to date way.

most pages have about 25 items and the code recognizes that but again, cannot locate the element to click on and will throw this

```
On Item:10 of 25
list index out of range
On Item:11 of 25
list index out of range
On Item:12 of 25
list index out of range
On Item:13 of 25
list index out of range
On Item:14 of 25
```

....

```
class InspectProducts:

def __init__(self):
    phantom_js_path = '/usr/bin/phantomjs'
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantom_js_path)
    self.driver.maximize_window()

 def test(self, url_path: str, category: str):
        self.driver.get(url_path)
        products = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('catProd-image-wrapper')
        for x in range(0, len(products)):

            try:
                print(f'On Item:{x} of {len(products)}')
                option = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('catProd-image-wrapper')[x]
                option.click()
                # on product page now
                product_name = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('prod-title').text
                label = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
                product_image_label = label[4].get_attribute('src')
           
                if product_image_label.endswith('uploadB.jpg') or product_image_label.endswith('uploadA.jpg'):
                    nutrition_label = product_image_label
                    print(nutrition_label)
                elif not product_image_label.endswith('uploadB.jpg') or not product_image_label.endswith('uploadA.jpg'):
                    nutrition_label = 'no label'

                product_description = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('productSectionContent').text
                product_rating = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span/span/span[1]')[0].text
                product_price = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/span')[0].text
                # you can print stuff here ..

                # back to product listing page
                self.utils.go_back_to_previous_page()
            except IndexError as e:
                print(e)
            print(f'ALL DONE {category}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inspect_products = InspectProducts()
    inspect_products.test('https://www.svncanada.com/list-amino-acid-blends.php', 'amino acids')
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is in java but this will help you load all your items first. Scroll till the end of the page and then start collecting data.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END);
```

you can also take help from this link [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)

Comment: Tried the translation of that ^ and it did not work