# Page scroll in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to scroll page using webdriver directly. I know how to scroll using javascript executor. My question is, can it be done without using java script??

With java script I was using following:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
```

Comment: does this answer it?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443067/scrolling-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to scroll to end of the page, you can do following:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
//OR
actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END)).perform();
```

If you want to scroll bit by bit, you can do following:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE).perform();
```

However if you want to scroll to a specific point on page, Java Script is your best bet.