# Getting Html of a jsp page from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

A jsp page in which dynamic datas are there.

I want to get the html of the jsp page which is shown in the browser , from the servlet.

I want to store the html of the jsp in a String variable.

is it possible to get the html source of the jsp file from a servlet.
If yes . How?

Comment: why do you want the html? If it is just to see what html is getting generated then you can "view source" from browser after the page is rendered. If not then ServletFilter is the only option that strikes me

Comment: Please explain why do u need to get generated HTML in your servlet, we can help then better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use commons http client, which helps in making GET or POST requests from java application.

You can pass all the data required like authentication params or.. session id's etc.

As per your requirement you can get content of completely rendered HTML source using the same.

Much more details can be found here along with good examples

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/userguide.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this is simply a matter of using the `wget` or `curl` command (or the Windows equivalent) to fetch the page and save it in a file.

(This won't work if the page contains Javascript that must be executed in order to fetch or render the data.  For that use-case, refer to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106268/command-line-url-fetch-with-javascript-capabliity).)