# how to get the content of JSP page from the Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to get the content of a jsp page from a servlet without redirect or forward, like a file for security issues, I'll process the HTML and write the new generated HTML in the servlet response. How can I do that?

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
if (request.getParameter("pageName").equals("index")) {
    //get index.jsp content and process it...
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details..

Comment: I have Servlet that receive a request from user .. in doPost method.
i want to get the content of JSP pages that corresponding to the requst.
ex:
if( request.getParameter("pageName").equals("index"))
 // i want to get all html of the page called index.jsp

Comment: Use request.getParameterNames() method iterate it and get individual values.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 
no. i want the whole html for any jsp page.

Comment: I understood that, I'm asking why would you need it?

Comment: @IbrahimAsad This question has been answered before [Getting HTML from Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447685/getting-html-of-a-jsp-page-from-a-servlet)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza
for security and i wont to write html inside servlet.

Comment: Do you know that won't make your application more secure? If you really want to add security to your Servlet responses, use a MVC framework with proven security like JSF or Spring.

Comment: Question not clear! Detail Required! What exactly u want..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a servlet, but you could do it in a Filter, in the doFilter method.  You would need to provide a wrapper around the response object, something like what they do [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/filters.html).