# What general approach can I take to parse the contents of a website?

Tags: web, web-scraping

Say someone else has a website generated by JavaScript, so I can't go look at the source and read what should be on the screen.  How can I grab the text on the screen so I can feed it into another program?  Also, how can I write a program that automatically clicks on radio buttons, links, etc. that satisfy certain criteria?

Comment: Do you need to _write_ the program? What if someone else has already written it, and will give it to you for free?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Well that's fine too :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good tool to screen-scrape with Javascript support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125177/whats-a-good-tool-to-screen-scrape-with-javascript-support)

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125177/whats-a-good-tool-to-screen-scrape-with-javascript-support. It looks like there are good answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a web scraping tool in Perl or Python. Or, you can use existing tools and frameworks to achieve that.

Check out [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), an open-source tool written in Python.

Take a look at [Selenium](http://selenium.openqa.org/) too.

Comment: This might shed some more light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125177/whats-a-good-tool-to-screen-scrape-with-javascript-support

Answer (score 1):

To parse dynamic content you could see the javascript source and get that same content the same way the webpage is getting it. (ie. replicating ajax calls and such)

If you want to submit data (not actually click on the elements) as if it were clicked/edited/selected you could also send a request containing the same data that the server is expecting by using some HTTP library, like [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). See an [example here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle content generated by script, then your first problem is to cause the script to execute. Further, the script will want to generate the content into a DOM. That means you need to *have* a DOM, and a script engine, and probably HTTP access to the Internet, and XML handling, etc.

If that sounds a lot like a web browser, then you're listening.

What you basically need is a web browser that you can control from a program. You'll need to be able to tell it to browse to a page, click buttons and links, etc., then you'll need to read back the resulting DOM.

Only *then* will you need to parse the page.

If you're in the Microsoft world, then you can use the WebBrowser control. There are several forms of this, and they all amount to the same thing: you can have Internet Explorer run *inside* of your program, and your program can control it.

I understand there are other browsers that can be controlled from a program, but since I don't know their details, I'll wait for someone else to tell us both.