# Getting content from page which checks for js

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

I am using "request" module to get page contents with following headers

```
var headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' };
```

still, the page I am trying to fetch somehow displays different content than View > Source from browser (looks like it detects for javascript support) , before diving into phantomjs (which I want to avoid due performance limitations) is there any way to get the html as it is on the browser?.
Thanks

Comment: You have to find what the website do when a browser hits it, and replicate it in your app

Comment: Just figured that out by reading this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303134/curl-request-on-a-page-requiring-javascript-support
... it must be cookie